# Django: Restrict frontend developer access to backend code

Tags: django, frontend, backend, development-environment, access-rights

We run a "classic" django website (rendering templates in the backend) and host the complete source code on github.

We also use the "classic" folder structure:

```
/source/         # For python related django code and packages
/templates/      # Just the normal django templates
/static/img/     # static images
/static/sass/    # Sass files
/static/css/     # Generated css files from sass (django-pipeline)
```

For the development purpose we use vagrant and ssh into the machine to start the django development server. Changes are pushed to github.

This is our current state and it works good for developer which are involved in the project.

**But** we also have for example external designers which should not have access to the backend.

**Problem**:
Designer should only have access to the /static/ folder (locally and on git) or if they also want to modify the html structure they need access to the /static/ and /templates/ folder.

So how can they run the Project without having access to the backend files? (Policy, installing and explaining vagrant is time consuming for non developers ...)

I couldn't find a solution but I have the following idea:

1. Create for the static folder a new repository
2. Create a server with everything what is needed to run the server
3. Mount the local /static/ (and /templates/) folder from the developer on the server. So that the local changes are served by the server. That way the designer don't need access to the backend source and also don't need the vagrant overhead. (Not sure how to solve this problem)

This is currently the only way which I see. Is there maybe a better solution and how can I implement step 3?

Comment: Don't designers need to be able to work on templates?

Comment: Yes you are right. If they also want to modify the html/templates they need also access to /templates/. I updated my question.

Comment: Docker might be an easier solution than Vagrant. I've only ever tried to use Vagrant once, but in all my recent projects over the last years we've been using Docker, and our designer was fine with. It also allows to run JS (e.g. via npm) builds for one page apps.